# How to generate 64 byte (512bit) random number

Tags: javascript, biginteger

I need to generate a 64-byte number in javascript. I want to do some math operations on it like `power` and `mod`. Is it any library to do these operations?

I checked [big.js](http://mikemcl.github.io/big.js/) but it has no random generator option. Also, I checked [Crypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/crypto) but seems that it can generate an array of numbers that is not good for pow and mod operations.

Comment: you can feed big.js with numbers generated by Crypto by adding and shifting the bits

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)